# Creating an Empty MVC Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I am using VS 2015 Enterprise and I'm trying to create an empty MVC project.

I go into the "Add | New Project..." dialog by right-clicking on the solution. I then select "Web" from the list along the left side and select "ASP.NET Web Application" as shown here:

[image]

Next, the following dialog window opens **but** the checkboxes for "Web Forms", "MVC" and "Web API" are all disabled. Does anyone know why they are disabled and how to enable them? Selecting "Web API" or "Web Application" (instead of "Empty") does not change the checkboxes' state -- they remain disabled.

If I recall correctly I used to be able to create an empty MVC project in VS 2013 with no problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you attempting to target the new ASP.net MVC 6 (that is still in release candidate), or the current ASP.net MVC 5? If you want to target the current release, select `Empty` at the top. If you want to target the Release Candidate, I don't think they have the templates set up the same way...empty is truly empty (my checkboxes are all greyed out as well). You'll need to manually add the MVC/StaticFiles/etc dependencies and update the Startup file.

Comment: @Sam I am targeting MVC 5, I realize that "empty is truly empty". I don't want that. I'd like to have the core references all brought in.

Comment: I'm a little confused... MVC 5, or ASP.net 5 (ASP.net Core 1.0)? If you aren't targeting the new release candidate stuff, you should be using the first `Empty` template.

Comment: @Sam I guessed I might be the one who's confused. I really meant MVC 5. So, from what you are saying, I should take the "Empty" under ASP.NET 4.6.1. Yes, I just did that and indeed it is an empty MVC 5. It's just what I wanted. Thanks!!!

Comment: Yeah, the **ASP.NET 5 Templates** are for the vNext stuff which is still in RC. I do hope that they will create an `Empty` template with the configuration all set up for MVC/StaticFiles/Error Handling/etc, but leave out the default controllers/ASP.net Identity/Bootstrap stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You can select Empty template along with MVC checkbox option which will give you MVC web application with empty Model, Views and Controller.
[image]

Comment: This should be a comment