# FileUpload1 does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm relatively new to web pages, especially asp.net/c# ones.  I'm following an example because I want to create a simple web page that will list files in a directory and let a person download the file listed, where the files shown are listed under the directory name, and using the filenames.  I found a [pretty good example that does that and a little extra (deleting)](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-list-of-files-from-Server-folder-in-ASPNet-GridView.aspx). I downloaded the solution and in trying to figure out how to edit/run it in visual studio 2015, I followed this [example which creates an empty mvc project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638984/creating-an-empty-mvc-project-in-visual-studio-2015). Then I right clicked the solution name and added an existing file (the CS.aspx.cs file and web.context from the downloaded solution, overwriting the existing web.config from VS when it asked. When I built the project, it was missing GridView1 (did not exist in current context), so I added this line

```
protected GridView GridView1;
```

which was suggested in [gridview1 missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41257016/the-name-gridview1-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context).

Now I'm trying to figure out why FileUpload1 is missing.  Do I need to add a

```
protected FileUpload FileUpload1
```

variable too? I saw other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548594/fileupload1-does-not-exist-in-current-context) that [said to add the id to the asp](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/the-name-fileupload-does-not-exist-in-the-current-asp-net), but I don't have that asp line that they said to add it to, and didn't think they were calling for it in the example I'm following.

This is the CS.aspx.cs from the example with my added Gridview definition added:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected GridView GridView1;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + fileName);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
    protected void DeleteFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        File.Delete(filePath);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

This is the web.config from the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
          The <authentication> section enables configuration 
          of the security authentication mode used by 
          ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
           The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
           of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
           during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
           it enables developers to configure html error pages 
           to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

           <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
             <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
             <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
           </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I do seem to have a web.config and also a Web.config in my project.  I'm not sure if that's an issue.

[image]

It seems like a huge extent for a simple windows based web page, but my boss wants me to use asp and c#.  Any ideas why it's missing FileUpload1 and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a control to a webform's ASPX page and use/modify it from the code-behind, you do need to declare it in the code-behind with the same name as the given ID for the ASPX.

```
public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected GridView GridView1;
    protected PhotoUpload PhotoUpload1;
    // more page code
}
```

If you're using the designer view to add controls, these definitions are typically added automatically to the generated 'MyPage.designer.cs'.

Either way, once you've added the definition to the back-end, you should be able to define the PhotoUpload control in the front-end ASPX like so:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

I recommend you get in the habit of more meaningful names than `GridView1` and `FileUpload1` early, as soon as you have multiple controls of the same type on your page it will get confusing trying to remember what `Label1` is used for when you're setting values for `Label6` and `Label4` as well.

Comment: The example didn't have the <asp:FileUpload1 line.  Maybe I don't need it? Why would I need more than they give?

Comment: @jonathan chase

Comment: @Michele the `<asp:FileUpload runat="server"/>` is the declaration of where you want it to sit on the actual page. If you don't declare it on the ASPX, you won't see it unless you add it to the page programmatically.

Comment: but if we have connected the aspx to the cs and the control id is defined in the aspx, then why can't it recognize the same name since we've told it the correct cs file

Comment: if i do like that it gives error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0102 The type 'UploadFile' already contains a definition for 'FileUploadControl' 1_UploadFile.aspx D:\partha\uploadfile1\uploadfile1\UploadFile.aspx.cs 12 Active Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0229 Ambiguity between 'UploadFile.FileUploadControl' and 'UploadFile.FileUploadControl' 1_UploadFile.aspx D:\partha\uploadfile1\uploadfile1\UploadFile.aspx.cs 19 Active